# Linux fedora tc qdisc gets "Error: Specified qdisc not found."

Tags: linux, fedora

I'm trying to run on Linux (fedora) this command:

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev enp2s0 handle 1:0 root netem delay 0 loss 1%
```

I checked the interface enp2s0 and the settings are fine, but I get this message:

```
Error: Specified qdisc not found.
```

what could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: I got the same when I run that command in a RedHat UBI image hosted in Centos8, but not on the same image when hosted on my mac. very weird

Answer (score 5):

If you're using a RedHat based distro, try installing the kernel-modules-extra package. That resolved the same problem for me.

Comment: This worked for me in Fedora 33. Thank you